# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to insert faculty data with POST request

Tags: java, mysql, postman, jersey

Hello I'm trying to insert data into multiple tables using one POST request with jersey. I don't know how to do it and this is the error so far:

[image: Error 500]

This is the json data that I'm trying to do the POST request:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "university_id": 1,
        "name": "FSHMN",
        "enrolled_students": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "username": "IN",
                "password": "admin",
                "fullname": "Depp",
                "email": "i@live.com",
                "subjects": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Programim 1",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 10,
                                "description": "Excellent"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Programim 2",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 9,
                                "description": "Very Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Calculus",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 8,
                                "description": "Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Discrete mathematics",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 7,
                                "description": "Well"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "username": "Student3",
                "password": "stu55",
                "fullname": "tudent",
                "email": "st@gmail.com",
                "subjects": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Programim 1",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 6,
                                "description": "Barely Passed"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Programim 2",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 6,
                                "description": "Barely Passed"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Calculus",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 7,
                                "description": "Well"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Discrete mathematics",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 8,
                                "description": "Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "username": "Johnn",
                "password": "d123",
                "fullname": "Doe",
                "email": "Johnny@gmail.com",
                "subjects": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Programim 1",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 9,
                                "description": "Very Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Programim 2",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 10,
                                "description": "Excellent"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Calculus",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 9,
                                "description": "Very Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Discrete mathematics",
                        "Grade": [
                            {
                                "grade_id": 0,
                                "mark": 8,
                                "description": "Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the the method that is called by the jersey request:

```
public Object insertFacultyStudentSubjectGrade(Faculty faculty,Student student, Subject subject, StudentMark mark) {
        Connection connection = null;
        String insertFaculty = "insert into faculty(fid,university_id,fname) values (?,?,?)";
        String insertStudent="insert into student(user_id,username,password,fullname,email) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        String insertSubject="insert into subject(id,name) values (?,?)";
        String insertGrade="insert into grade(mark,description) values(?,?)";

        try {
            connection = new MysqlDbConnectionService().getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertFaculty);
            ps.setInt(1, faculty.getFid());
            ps.setInt(2, faculty.getUniversityid());
            ps.setString(3, faculty.getFname());
            ps.execute();

            PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement(insertStudent);
            ps1.setString(1, student.getId());
            ps1.setString(2, student.getUsername());
            ps1.setString(3, student.getPassword());
            ps1.setString(4, student.getFullName());
            ps1.setString(5, student.getEmail());
            ps1.execute();

            PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement(insertSubject);
            ps2.setInt(1, subject.getId());
            ps2.setString(2, subject.getName());
            ps2.execute();

            PreparedStatement ps3 = connection.prepareStatement(insertGrade);
            ps3.setInt(1,mark.getMark());
            ps3.setString(2,mark.getDescription());
            ps3.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e + "Data insert unsuccessful");
        }
        return faculty;

    }
```

This is the Jersey method:

```
@Path("faculty/fs")
@POST
public Response addFacultyStudentSubjectGrade(String payload) {

Faculty faculty = new Gson().fromJson(payload, Faculty.class);
Student student = new Gson().fromJson(payload, Student.class);
Subject subject = new Gson().fromJson(payload, Subject.class);
StudentMark mark = new Gson().fromJson(payload, StudentMark.class);

return Response.ok(new Gson().toJson(facultyService.insertFacultyStudentSubjectGrade(faculty,student,subject,mark))).build();
```

}

This is the **ER DIAGRAM**:

[image: ER DIAGRAM]

**Here are my Classes**:

**Faculty Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Faculty {


    @SerializedName("id")
    private int fid;

    @SerializedName("university_id")
    private int university_id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String fname;

    @SerializedName("enrolled_students")
    private List<Student> studentList;





    public Faculty() {
        this.fid = fid;
        this.university_id=university_id;
    }

    public  void setFid(int fid)
    {

        this.fid = fid;
    }

    public int getFid()
    {

        return fid;
    }

    public  void setUniversityid(int university_id)
    {

        this.university_id=university_id;
    }

    public int getUniversityid()
    {

        return university_id;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname)
    {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getFname()
    {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList()
    {
        return studentList;
    }



}
```

**Student Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;
public class Student {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("fullname")
    private String fullName;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("subjects")
    private List<Subject> subjectList;
    public Student() {
    }
    public Student(String id, String username, String password, String fullName, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }
    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
}
```

**Subject Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Subject {




    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Professor")
     private List<Professor> professorList;

    @SerializedName("Grade")
    private List<StudentMark> markList;


    public Subject() {
        this.id = id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public  void setId(int id)
    {
      this.id=id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }


    public List<Professor> getProfessorList() {
        return professorList;
    }

    public void setProfessorList(List<Professor> professorList) {
        this.professorList = professorList;
    }

    public List<StudentMark> getMarkList() {
        return markList;
    }

    public void setMarkList(List<StudentMark> markList) {
        this.markList = markList;
    }
}
```

**StudentMark Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;

public class StudentMark {
    private int grade_id;
    private int mark;
    private String description;


    public int getGrade_id() {
        return grade_id;
    }

    public void setGrade_id(int grade_id) {
        this.grade_id = grade_id;
    }

    public int getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

I know my methods are wrong and don't know how to properly do it so can someone solve this or give me suggestions on how this level of complexity should be done properly.

Comment: I think your payload is suggesting Array of Faculty cause it is starting with [ whereas your code is expecting it to be just single instance of Faculty so it is giving error while parsing

Comment: Are you able to write proper methods that work based on my ER Diagram?

Comment: Thank you for the answer Yes it solved the Error 500 but I have problem with the methods. How do I rewrite them so they can make the required post request?